# TFS 2017 Web API - how to get the name of Build Agent?

Tags: rest, tfs

I am trying to get the name of the agent that executed a given build from the TFS Web API.

There is a LOT of great details in there, but the Agent that ran the build does not seem to be in there.  This is a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to the timeline of the build:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

This will return a [`Timeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1#timeline), which has an array of [`TimelineRecords`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1#timelinerecord). The `workerName` of the timeline records contains the name of the agent running the operation.

Comment: Yuk.  So if I want the agent for 250 builds I Have to make 250 calls lol  Thank you though! :D